# calling method outside of form tag in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

i am using some buttons outside of form tag that when clicked need to call method from code behind file. the problem is it doesn't look possible with asp.net web forms as it require everything in form tag so to use code behind file.

my problem is design based . i can't place everything inside form tag . here is my code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div>
        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent2" runat="server">
    <div style="width:30%;margin:0 auto; padding-top:50px">
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="help" href="#">
            <i class="fa  fa-question"></i> Got Questions
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" href="#" id="validate_Click" style="margin-left:40px;">
            <i class="fa  fa-check-square"></i> Validate
        </a>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#help").click(function () {
            swal("Here's a message!");
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Why you can't place every thing in form tag?

Comment: i need the buttons aligned underneath the place where i am using the drag and drop

Comment: When you have master page all  things between content place holder is between form.(The masterpage form)

Comment: Where is the place you are drag and drop?

Comment: it is the content1 area

Comment: Content1 is for head element of the page(in default). Do you want to drag and drop into head of your page?!

Comment: You are right about the problem being designed based, the design flaw is ASP.NET Web Form's and the design patterns it forces developers to follow. But if you insist on using draconian architecture, you can have all your content in one form, place form in master page.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you said some thing about drag and drop. Content place holders are not physical elements, They have not width and height, and they are not related to your drag and drop. When you have a master page and a .aspx file based on, Asp.Net merges them and It likes all thinks between

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent2" runat="server">
    <span>hello</span>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

are between the master page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent2" runat="server">
    <span>hello</span>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

And with other things in master page they finally make an html file.